# Which conditions imply $\sup_n |\ln x_n| < \infty$?

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value, supremum-and-infimum

I want to find conditions which imply that $\sup_n|\ln x_n| < \infty$. Intuitively I think that $\inf_n x_n > 0$ and $\sup_n x_n < \infty$ should be enough, but I don't know how to write it formally. Are there any properties I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $|\log x_n| \le A$ for all $n$ if and only if 
$$
-A \le \log x_n \le A \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad e^{-A} \le x_n \le e^A.
$$

Therefore, you see that

- If $A = \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} |\log x_n| < \infty$, then $e^{-A} \le \inf_{n \in \mathbb N} x_n$ and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} x_n \le e^A$.
- If $\inf_{n \in \mathbb N} x_n > 0$ and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} x_n < \infty$, let $B = \max \{ -\log(\inf_{n \in \mathbb N} x_n), \log(\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} x_n) \}$. Then $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} |\log x_n| \le B$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Could you elaborate more why $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n \leq e^{-A}$, please?

Comment: @Kolibris : Sorry I put it the wrong way around... I was typing the answer on my phone so I couldn't see everything clearly. See correction. I just meant the obvious thing, nothing fancy.

Comment: Now I can understand it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you start with those assumptions,  then assume the $sup_n |\ln x_n|=\infty$ and you can quickly get a contradiction.  That says that there exists a subsequence that is unbounded.   That means you must have an infinite amount of $\ln x_n$ that are unbounded to $\infty$,  or that arbitrarilly approach 0.   If That would contradict your two assumptions.

That shows your two conditions are sufficient.   To show they are necessary, assume one of them is not true,  and you immediately can get a subsequence of $\sup_n |\ln x_n|$ that is unbounded.  Hence they are necessary and sufficient